# Registering a custom validator in Zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I create a custom date Validator. But I keep getting this **error message**:

> "Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or
>   create an instance for date_validator"

I did some research and tried adding in **module.config.php** after the view manager array.

```
'validators' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'date_validator' => 'Administrativo\InputFilter\Date_Validator'
    ),
),
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in the class name? (Especially the underscore) What editor are you using? If you have PHP 5.5+, you should always use ::class for class names. Otherwise, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration seems okay.

Are you sure you have a file (invokable class) with the name `Date_Validator` in a folder `Administrativo\InputFilter` in your module?

Is the namespace inside this class `Administrativo\InputFilter` and is the class name `Date_Validator`.

It is important that both the ***class name*** and ***namespace*** have to be correct as well as the ***folder names*** and ***file name***. Otherwise the PluginManager will not be able to find your file.

---

### UPDATE

If all that is fine then there is something else you should check.

If you build your input filters through config array then you should make sure that [the factory inside your `InputFilter`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/blob/master/src/InputFilter.php#L40) class holds a correctly populated `InputFilterPluginManager` instance (with both `ValidatorManager` and `FilterManager` on board). Otherwise [it will not inject those classes in the `setInputFilterManager` method](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-inputfilter/blob/master/src/Factory.php#L117) and it will [later create a new empty plugin manager instance](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-validator/blob/master/src/ValidatorChain.php#L69) which will obviously not hold your validator class.

Comment: yes, I already double checked for this kind of typos. I am importing the class inside my filter file (use Administrativo\InputFilter\Date_Validator as date_validator;) and then on my file I have this piece of code.

Comment: Hi wilt, no it didn't work out. I had to put in module.config.php:
'invokables' => array(
        Administrativo\InputFilter\Date_Validator'
     => 'Administrativo\InputFilter\Date_Validator'
    ), and then worked. Tnx for your time!